# Кто популярнее: русский Stack Overflow или английский?

Tags: поддержка, популярность

Тут мне стало интересно, какой из ресурсов преуспевает в популярности `Stack Overflow` на русском или английском.

Comment: Даже странно что такой вопрос возник. На английский ходит весь мир, на русский сами понимаете.

Comment: Что такое "популярность" и что такое "преуспевание" в ней?

Comment: @Эникейщик  **На английский ходит весь мир, на русский ходит лучшая его часть :3**. Извините что перефразировал вашу фразу но _прям с языка снял_. вот :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Достаточно зайти и посмотреть [общую статистику по сайтам](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

```
                              Вопросов   Ответов   Участников   Визитов в день  Вопросов в день
Stack Overflow                 19 млн     28 млн     11 млн        11 млн             6900
Stack Overflow на русском      290 тыс    327 тыс    176 тыс       81 тыс             195
```